# fastest way of sending messages to clients from a server

Tags: tcp, udp, webserver, xmpp, nat-traversal

I want to make an application that sends thousands of messages per second. These would be very small messages only a few characters each but also would be very rapid potentially 10-20 per second per client. The messages will be sent only from the server to different clients and coud potentially be up to 10,000 user at once so that is 200,000 messages per second.

These could be sent to clients on 3g and or wifi.

What do you think is capable of doing this? A xmpp application, udp messages with NAT traversal, or something else that I havent thought of yet?

Comment: Are you sending the same message to all clients (e.g. multicasting), or are you sending (potentially) different messages to each client?  Are you concerned with reliability - i.e. if a few messages fail to make it to one or two clients is this an issue, or would you want the server to be informed so that it could resend the message / handle the issue appropriately?  Are you bound to any particular technologies to develop this in / host this on?

Comment: Sounds like phantom requirements for vapor ware .. unless there is extensive previous experience in this (which it does not sound like), the first attempt will at those numbers will be "just a prototype". So just write it. Then learn and adapt. Make sure it fulfills the other requirements first.

Comment: I also facing same problem using XMPP. I want to send (50-60 msg per sec)  from one client to other client. the messages are very small (only 20 chars) but lot of delay happens. If any one know how solve this problem please help me.